# Uncaught TypeError: Map.addLayer is not a function earth engine javascript api

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to the Google Earth Engine javascript api. Sorry if my question is silly.
I have included ee_api_js.js file from the git library of Google Earth Engine javascript api. I have validated the user with the ee.data.authenticate method successfully. Now when I am trying to add layer to map it gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Map.addLayer is not a function"

```js
var map, ee;

function initMap() {
      var latlng = {lat: 31.046051, lng: 34.851612};
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 8, center: latlng, disableDefaultUI: true});
    }

var runAnalysis = function() {
            ee.initialize();
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180521T081559_20180521T082244_T36SYB'); 
            var visParams_ndvi = {min: 0.1, max: 0.9, palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
                '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'};
            var image_ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
            map.addLayer(image_ndvi,visParams_ndvi,'NDVI');
    };


    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$('#date').flatpickr();

        // Shows a button prompting the user to log in.
        var onImmediateFailed = function() {
            ee.data.authenticateViaPopup(function() {
                // If the login succeeds, hide the login button and run the analysis.
                //$('.g-sign-in').addClass('hidden');
                runAnalysis();
              });
        };

        // Attempt to authenticate using existing credentials.
        ee.data.authenticate(CLIENT_ID, runAnalysis, null, null, onImmediateFailed);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `map` is not a `ui.Map` from the EE library.  It's a `google.maps.Map` which is different.  [This is a detailed example](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/demos/map-layer/static/script.js) showing how to call `getMap()` on your EE object and passing the token and id to the maps API.

Comment: Thanks, what's the best way so that i can use the same code of google earth engine console using javascript api, I don't want to go with python.

Comment: Is there any documentation available for ee_api_js.js which shows how to use their functions?